# Drag and Drop Across Windows

Tags: jquery-ui, yui

I have a page that loads and then that page's JavaScript opens a popup window that will become a gallery. The user will upload images, using JavaScript and PHP that is part of the popup gallery window, and these uploaded  images will be displayed in the gallery window that we popped up

Once several images have been uploaded and displayed in the gallery window I would like to drag and drop them into the primary window. Actually I'd like to leave the image in the gallery and just drag a ghost image across and drop it in the main window, so we end with the image in both windows.

This seems a bit tricky since the main widow and the popup gallery window are different JavaScript execution contexts.  How can I implement a jQuery (or YUI) Drag and Drop that works from the popup window to the main window?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this plugin can help you:

http://dragsort.codeplex.com/

Comment: Dragsort is a godsend!  I was not aware of it before your comment. I don't think it will actually solve the problem above because it almost certainly requires that all the elements be in the same DOM, which isn't the case where there are two Window objects.  But it solves beautifully the next problem I have of getting Drag and Drop to be smart enough to know when something is already at the drop point and then move it out of the way first before doing the drop.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy it solved your another problem. For other problem, what if you do your popup window with fancybox? This will allow you to create popup just as a div and this will be the same DOM document which can be than managed by AJAX calls and javascript...